# Does Material UI Theme for React components follow same guidelines as Material Design Theme for android components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to ReactJS and am implementing a theme for my web app. When I develop android applications, I customize my theme and the material components use the theme's color by default.

For example if I have my `color_on_primary` set to `#ffffff` then the Material Button component by default will use that color for its icon tint.

Do Material UI components do the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes. In order for this to work there are some steps that you should follow.
With material-ui it is recommended to use createMuiTheme() for your theme. Below is how you use it.

```
// theme.js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    // Color of the button if you use <Button color="primary"></Button>
    primary: {
      main: "#FF9F1C"
    },
    // Color of the button if you use <Button color="secondary"></Button>
    secondary: {
      main: "#2EC4B6"
    },
  },
  typography: {
    // General button css
    button: {
      fontFamily: "'Montserrat', sans-serif",
      textTransform: null,
      fontSize: 16
    }
  },
})

export default theme
```

Then you'd have a ThemeProvider component where you pass in your theme you just created.

```
// example.js
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from 'theme.js'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  // Some extra styling if you'd like
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export default function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary" className={classes.button}>I'm a button</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I highly recommend you to check API of the material-ui components.

Material-UI Button API -> https://material-ui.com/api/button/

If you look at the Props section of the component you can see that color prop will use you theme if provided. It is hard to grasp at first but you will get used to it.